# Running a PHP Script with Cron From Cygwin

Tags: php, cygwin, cron, cron-task

I want to push my `cron.txt` to crontab using something like:

```
crontab cron.txt
```

The contents of my cron.txt file are:

```
# Format : minute | hour | day-of-month | month | day-of-week | path-to-script

0 1600 * * 4 C:/path/to/myscript.php
```

I am getting the error:

```
"cron.txt":4: bad hour
```

How can I run the script properly? Is all that is needed the time and the path to php file?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to run it at 4pm every thursday?

Comment: Alright, so I just realized the hour should be `16` and not `1600`. But what about the script path?

Comment: I guess that 1600 is an invalid hour. I'm not sure about it

Comment: @Darren - Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have fixed the invalid hour issue, now if your php script is accessible via the web, why don't you use a `curl` request as your command?

```
0 16 * * 4 curl --request GET 'http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/myscript.php'
```

<sup>*Obviously you'd need to secure it, probably with a custom get key or even in `.htaccess`, only allowing server access.*</sup>

Comment: thanks, this is nifty, but do you know how to run it from a local php file?

Comment: @navlag Remember cron tasks are to run native linux tasks, so try this - `/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/myscript.php` :)

Answer (score 1):

The hour parameter should be an hour with no minutes (16 not 1600).
As for the path, you need to tell cygwin how it should be executed: try adding php to the start.

```
# Format : minute | hour | day-of-month | month | day-of-week | path-to-script
0 16 * * 4 php C:/path/to/myscript.php
```